# how to fire dropdownlist.selectedindexchanged event programmatically

Tags: asp.net

I have some code which fires when user selects an item in dropdownlist. Now I want the same code to fire when I set selectedindex programmatically.

I have tried setting

```
ddlSystemLevelDCP.SelectedIndex=2;
```

and this as well

```
ddlSystemLevelDCP.SelectedValue="2";
```

None of them fires this event. However when user changes the selection, this event fires.

Comment: you mean in fires auto post back?

Comment: are you sure the index is changing?

When the selected item is index 2, and you set it to 2 in code, the selection isn't changed so the event will no be triggered.

Answer (score 11):

Set your selected index. say, 2 and then call that event with null arguments.

```
ddlSystemLevelDCP.SelectedIndex=2;
ddlSystemLevelDCP_SelectedIndexChanged(null,null);
```

This should work.

Answer (score 8):

If you have event handler, you can call it.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSystemLevelDCP" runat="server"
AutoPostBack="true"
onselectedindexchanged="ddlSystemLevelDCP_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>
...
...
...
ddlSystemLevelDCP_SelectedIndexChanged(ddlSystemLevelDCP,EventArgs.Empty);
```

Comment: it throws stackoverflow exception.

Comment: This worked for me. No issues. Not sure why OP is getting exception

Comment: Worked for me as well.  Thank you! The compiler didn't accept null arguments, but it did accept the name of the dropdown list and EventArgs.empty as arguments.